# Google Apps Script Trigger Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, spreadsheet

The new Google Spreadsheets have add-ons like Google Analytics. They can generate an report using the GA API.
Now I need to programmatically trigger this add-on function. However the add-on is not a script with functions, but a black box it seems. There are scheduleable triggers to run my own defined functions, but I see no way to talk to the add-on and start the "get data" function it provides to the user (within the Spreadsheet UI).
Is there any way to run the add-on on a scheduled basis?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think so.

If methods in an add-on could be called programmatically, that add-on would be [published as a Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries).  I did some digging and found the key of the Google Analytics add-on ("M6DHyOggPdtxTHKxmzonxqGg3No8Xsi1r"), tried to add it, and got the error:

[image: You do not have access to library GoogleAnalytics, used by your script, or it has been deleted]

A workaround might be to programmatically emulate a click on the appropriate menu item, but I don't believe that is currently supported by Apps Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the Google Analytics add-on. But the Supermetrics add-on also connects to Google Analytics and can be set to refresh with time-based triggers: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/supermetrics/bnkdidgbiidpnohlnhmkehlimlnfhgce